# Using FittedModel without clashing symbols

Tags: fitting, code-request

For some FittedModel, the "BestFitParameters" are given in terms of the symbols used to define the model.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[{10,11,12},a*x+c,{a,c},x];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

returns `{a->1.,c->9.}`

This can be problematic if I define `a` or `c` somewhere else. One option is to use the model in a module, and try to localize variables but this generates unique keys that I have to keep track of:

```
fit=Module[ {a,c}, NonlinearModelFit[{10,11,12},a*x+c,{a,c},x] ];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

returns `{a$768206 -> 1., c$768206 -> 9.}`

Often I'll do something like

```
fit=Module[ {a,c,lf},  lf=NonlinearModelFit[{10,11,12},a*x+c,{a,c},x]; {"a"->a,"c"->c}/lf];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

which returns `{"a"->1.,"c"->9.}` with strings as keys.

I actually prefer this since now `"a"` and `"c"` can't clash with a definition of the symbols `a` or `c`, but it's a pain because I lose access to the `FittedModel` object which may be useful later on.

Since I can't use the strings `"a"` or `"c"` in the `NonlinearModelFit` function, my question is this: Is there a way to modify the `FittedModel` object, such that requesting `"BestFitParameters"` returns the a list of rules with strings as the keys?

Alternatively, does anyone have a more elegant way of working with these objects, so I don't have to keep track of what symbols I use in fits and make sure not to use the same symbols to define similar values elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use formal symbols, e.g., [`\[FormalA]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalA) or [`\[FormalC]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalC)? These symbols are protected, so they should never acquire a value:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
    {10,11,12},
    \[FormalA] x + \[FormalC], {\[FormalA], \[FormalC]}, x
];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
fit[3]
```

> [image]

Comment: I didn't even know these existed! Thanks for the option.

Comment: Just a note, you can get a normal characters with `esc-$a-esc` or `\[FormalA]`, greeks are available too, but you have to spell out the letter, `esc-$Beta-esc` or `\[FormalBeta]` - you can't use the character.

Answer (score 2):

One straightfoward way to handle this is to accept the unique keys generated inside the module and write a function that replaces these with de-unique-ified strings when the best fit parameters are needed:

```
getBestFit[fit_FittedModel] := Module[
   {a, c, bf, newKeys, x, oldkeys},
   bf = fit["BestFitParameters"];
   oldkeys = Keys@bf;
   newKeys = First /@ StringSplit[ToString /@ oldkeys, "$"];
   Rule @@@ Transpose@{newKeys, oldkeys /. bf}
   ];

fit = Module[
   {a, c, x},
   NonlinearModelFit[{10, 11, 12}, a*x + c, {a, c}, x]
   ];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

shows that the unique symbols generated inside the module are retained

```
{a$772530 -> 1., c$772530 -> 9.}
```

while

```
getBest@fit
```

returns the desired rules with strings as keys

```
{"a"->1.,"c"->9.}
```